# Need help with wiring a combination two way switch

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm trying to swap out an existing two way combo switch with a new. When I pulled it out, the right side terminals had three wires. Two black and a red. On the left side there was one black. My new outlet only has space for two wires on the right and left. How do I wire properly? Thanks, new here[image][image][image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the situation with the old switch, as well as the make and model of the new switch? Also, where are you on this planet?

Comment: Yes I'll get a photo when I get a chance. But it was in the order, top down, black, black, red.

Comment: Where are you on this planet, for that matter?

Comment: Screw positions don't mean anything at all on switches. What matters is the terminal function, and every model puts the terminals in different places.

Comment: Save the box because the diagram is usually printed inside.

Comment: Also it's a Leviton 15A 120 combo 2 switch, model no 5224.

Comment: There is a diagram as Normal but they only show two wires on each side. So why three "hot" wires and only one load?

Comment: Your may have an extra hot wire that actually goes to another switch or receptacle or fixture someplace else. That is especially likely if it has a matching white in a bundle of white neutrals. **Pictures!**

Comment: Just a general thought, can you connect a red wire with a black since the red is considered hot?

Comment: Three "hot" wires and 1 "load" is incorrect for that switch. The source data is wrong or misinterpreted.  Your question about red wires may explain all this: you are expecting hot wires to be color-coded *by function*.  Doesn't work that way.  Hots are any color other than white/gray (neutral) or green/bare (ground).  If you want them color coded,  you can retape them colors after you identify them; I do exactly that.

Comment: Photos added in original post. The combo switch goes to a pantry and the garage light. When I wired the new outlet without the red, the garage light didn't work, so clearly goes to garage. and now that I notice it, the garage light also has switch out by the side door in garage. So perhaps that's my problem, I need a three way combo switch since that light is controlled from two switches.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel In the US at least, I would guess, since there's a wire nut in the box.

Comment: @TylerH -- yeah, the OP's wiring is pretty archetypically North American (some of the verbiage in their original post had me tripped up for a bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You need to return the switch you got and get a single-pole/3-way combination switch instead of a single-pole/single-pole

Your existing combination switch has a normal single pole switch on the top and a 3-way (two location) switch on the bottom, while it sounds like your new switch consists of two single pole switches, which won't help you with your garage light very much.  So, as you are suspecting, you'll need to take it back and get the correct thing; fortunately, it shouldn't be that much harder to find.

### As to how this was wired

The good news is that we can identify the functions of the old wires from here.  Clearly, since the black wire on the left is shared between both halves of the old switch, it must be the always-hot feed in.  From the terminal screws on the right,  the top one is connected to the black switched-hot for the light controlled by the top (single-pole) switch, while the bottom two screws connect to the black and red wires that serve as the *travellers* to the garage light.

You'll need to remember what these wires *do*, though, since the positions of the screws on the new switch isn't going to help you any, only the fact that the common screws on said replacement will be a different color.  Also note that NEC 404.9(B) permits snap switches to be grounded by their screws, so don't worry about running a grounding pigtail to your switch.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's helpful. Once I realized there was another switch in the garage today I figured it was a three way (recently bought the house so still discovering).

Comment: @Diyhomenoah -- we thank people around here by upvoting and/or accepting their answers :)

Comment: No clue how to do that, would be happy to. Just joined

Comment: @Diyhomenoah -- there is a score, up/down arrows, and a grey checkmark on the left side of questions & answers here (the checkmark accepts answers, the up/down arrows do what you'd expect to the score)